# Using Twitter API - OAuth Callback URLs won't work when developing in a local environment

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, callback, twitter-oauth

I am developing an app that uses the Twitter API for authorisation. The app is developed with PHP and CodeIgniter.

My problem is that I'm using MAMP on my Mac, in combination with VirtualHostX. VHX lets you develop using any URL you like, pointed to a local directory - for example, `http://dev.mysite`.

When OAuth sends me back to my callback URL like this, nothing happens. Setting it to a 'real' live URL on the Internet works fine and without a problem.

So how can I get local, VHX URLs to work with Twitter OAuth?

Thanks

Jack

Comment: Can you be more specific about you issue? Can you get a request token? Do you return the the correct callback URL after authorizing on Twitter? Is the oauth_token parameter present when you return to the callback URL? Can you get an access token?

Answer (score -1):

Twitter doesnot alllow you to register an application unless you provide a real live URL.
 You should look for some free hosting with phpsupport to run such an application...